# How to cite ebooks that have no pagination in intext cittion in MLA7?

Tags: writing, citation-style

I'm writing my dissertation and the novel I'm working on is an ebook.

I tried looking for the paperback, but the English version is not available in my country. I tried checking on the web but all versions I found are epub or pdfs without page number.

My problem is about the intext citation. I checked citation guides and all I could find is that I can use only the paragraph or the chapter number. I think it will be weird to analyse several emphasized text quotes from the novel without mentioning their exact location.

So I was wondering whether I can use the page number mentioned in the adobe reader?

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about what is "correct" for your dissertation, I think you will need to check with your adviser -- I think different people might have different perspectives, and you'll only know what those judging your work will expect if you ask them.

From a more utilitarian perspective, I'd say listing the chapter number is ideal. Only the most critical or curious readers will follow the citation; for such readers, it will not be a terrible inconvenience to flip through a few pages to find the exact passage. The chapter number should be enough to get them to what they need.

I would *not* list the page number that shows up in Adobe Reader, because it's going to be arbitrary, a function of the text size, page size, font, etc. that you have chosen. The function of a footnote is to *help* the reader find the text, but using arbitrary page numbers may have the effect of *hindering* them, as they may not immediately realize why the numbers they're looking at don't correspond to yours.